# Is vHub Updater for VisualHub legit?

Tags: macos, upgrade, 3rd-party

I got a newsletter to go to `store.kagi.com` It's an offer to buy an update to the discontinued video converting software Visualhub by Techspansion. What makes it a bit suspicious that there is no contact whatsoever to ask if this is the real deal. I'm a fan of Visualhub no question but an anon update to a discontinued product? Would you buy this though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
Techspansion is not affiliated with the product "vHub Updater" by Kagi.
"vHub Updater" makes unauthorized use of Techspansion's copyrighted code.
Techspansion does not support "vHub Updater" and does not recommend its use.
Our official (and free) patches for Lion are at http://www.techspansion.com

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! So they basically hijacked Visualhub, this is crazy ...